# postgres db trigger to log query type into another table

Tags: postgresql, triggers

This problem scenario may sounds strange but I am trying to write a trigger to log the query type into another table and so far i havent been able to find anything on google

the database i am using is postgres

i.e.

if i have two tables; table1 and querylog(has a string field called querytype)

and a select query is executed on table1, i want to insert a row into the query log table with the querytype field populated with "select"

anyone have any idea how to reference the query type in a function that will be called by a trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triggers do not get called for `SELECT` queries, so that won't work.

If you want to audit queries, you can use the PostgreSQL log file or tools like [pgaudit](http://pgaudit.org/) that hook into PostgreSQL to retrieve and log the information.

Comment: haha poor scenario example on my part. thanks so much! this pgaudit tool does everything im looking for.